# ASP.NET MVC IE 8 not posting data

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8

Error occurs when certain clients post data to MVC login page
All this information was captured via wireshark on my server (i know thats a bad idea but i cant figure out any other way to debug)

```
POST /MVC/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fMVC%2fAzureMail%2fSearch HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*
Referer: <<REDACTED>>/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fMVC%2fAzureMail%2fSearch
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Alexa Toolbar)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: rips.liginsurance.com
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=uagclbsh4feh0necioqyzome; ASPSESSIONIDQCDBTBBB=JAKJPJLBBADIJGNEEMBDIOHH
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFASgKAAAADw==
```

The referring login page (and response to the post)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 30 Dec 2011 20:30:49 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5264

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log On</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        td
        {
            font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MVC/Content/Site.css" />
    <link href="/MVC/Content/RiPS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/MVC/Content/2011.1.315/telerik.simple.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/MVC/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/MVC/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//s3.amazonaws.com/modernizr.custom.94195.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/MVC/Content/override.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<body>
    <table id="MainBodyTable"  style="padding: 0;border: 3px black solid;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0px; width: 100%; margin: 0;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 45%; background-color: #3399FF;">
                <h1 style="font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    LIG Marine Managers </h1>
                    <span style="font: 6pt; visibility: hidden;">v1.52</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 10%; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;" >
                <!--<a href="/Images/RiPS.JPG">CLICKTOTEST</a>-->
                <a href="http://<<REDACTED>>" target="_top">
                    <img src="http://<<REDACTED>>/Images/RiPS.JPG" height="84"  alt="" style="margin: 0 auto; border: none;" /></a>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 45%; background-color: #3399FF; text-align: right;">
                <h1 style="font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    LIG Marine Managers
                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                <div style="margin: 0 auto;">


<h2>Log On</h2>
<p>
    Please enter your user name and password. <a href="/MVC/Account/Register">Register</a> if you don't have an account.
</p>

<script src="/MVC/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/MVC/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="validation-summary-errors"><span>Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.</span>
<ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>

<form action="/MVC/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fMVC%2fAzureMail%2fSearch" method="post">    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <label for="UserName">User name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true">The User name field is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
                <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true">The Password field is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
                <label for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fico.css">
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.datauri && Modernizr.generatedcontent,
            yep: 'fico_embedded.css',
            nope: ['fico.css', '/MVC/Scripts/views/ficoPolyfill.js']
        });
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: login was unsuccessful? is that the issue? theres more info needed here. whats the auth on the server side, whats failing there? sql auth, windows auth, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in the HTML that might be causing the form to be posted incorrectly. You are defining the HTML tag twice if it is IE. At the very beginning and before the BODY tag.

Comment: I think he put up both the form before and after the post in the same block of code there.

Comment: epignosisx looks to be right.  I did have HTML declared twice now to test that was the issue